# Pipe failed error when trying to edit file in Midnight commander

Tags: linux, windows-10, docker, midnight-commander

I am trying to setup Docker container for development. I have Windows 10 Pro 19044.2251, so I installed Docker Desktop, fixed WSL 2, run container like

```
docker run --name Fresh -it --gpus all ubuntu sh
```

installed mc into it (apt-get update
apt-get install -y mc),
then I needed to open another CLI with button in Docker Desktop and now if I run mc and try to view or edit any file (F3/F4) in it, I get "pipe failed" error message, which is btw quite hard to remove (needs a dozen of mouse clicks outside it). How to fix this?

mcedit  from command line works properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was no `/bin/sh`. So I made:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/dash /bin/sh
```

It helped to me. Or `ln -s /usr/bin/bash /bin/sh` if you have no `dash` shell installed.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser... Did you need root privileges (e.g. `sudo`) to create the link?

Comment: Yes. `/bin` directory is protected.

Comment: ...Then feel you free to [edit] your post adding _our_ secret `;-)`

Comment: Updated. Thanks. :-)